# function does not return to the main function

Tags: c++

I need to write a program that if it increase order than return true, if it is not return false
it is right way to return the function?

```
int main()
{
    int n1;
    int n2;
    int n3;
    cout << "enter" << endl;
    cin >> n1 >> n2 >> n3;
    if (inOrder(n1, n2, n3))
        cout << "ture" << endl;
    else
        cout << "false" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

bool inOrder(int n1, int n2, int n3)
{
    return (n1 < n2) && (n2 <= n3);
}
```

Comment: Your logic seems sound to me. Do you have any indication that it does the wrong thing? Perhaps `return (n1 <= n2) && (n2 <= n3);` would be better - or `return (n1 < n2) && (n2 < n3);`. Just use the same condition. The first would say `true` for `1 1 1` but not the second. It'd require at least `1 2 3`.

Comment: What you have posted seems a reasonable start to me. The traditional method for validating code is to test it.  I recommend you remove the user input for now and call `inOrder` with a variety of numbers chosen to test the corner conditions where things could go wrong and a sampling of other number to make sure the program  also works where it should work to ensure that it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the *loop* versions in C++. `for`, `while` or `do-while`. This is an example of the latter, the `do-while`:

```
#include <iostream>

bool inOrder(int n1, int n2, int n3) {
    // require n2 to be larger than n1 and n3 to be larger than n2
    return (n1 < n2) && (n2 < n3);
}

int main() {
    int n1;
    int n2;
    int n3;

    do { // start of loop, do this while something is true

        std::cout << "enter three integers: ";
        std::cin >> n1 >> n2 >> n3;

       // condition - go back to "do" if the while condition evaluates to "true"
       // (that is, if "inOrder" returns false)

    } while( inOrder(n1, n2, n3) == false ); 
}
```